# Nuxt JS route validation doesn't redirect to error page

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have an app with Nuxt JS, and there is a route called posts that accepts parameters like so: .../posts/_id. When someone goes to /posts/put_news, they get post with name "Put News" and so on.

So, I wrote a validation method like so:

```js
    async validate({ params }) {
  // await operations
  const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/listings_names')
         var response_data = response.data
        
         var str = (params.id).split('_').join(' ')
  
         const arr2 = str.split(" ");
  
  for (var i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
      arr2[i] = arr2[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + arr2[i].slice(1);
  
  }
  
  const str2 = arr2.join(" ");
  
  
  var id_fix = str2
  
  const obj =  response_data.find(o => o.name == id_fix);
console.log(obj)
 
  if (obj == undefined){
console.log('undefied, false')
    return false

 
  }
  else{
    return true;
  }

},
```

The code does return false, but does nothing else. Once it returns "false" I expect nuxt to redirect the user to the error page, but it just stays on that page. I looked on the documentation, and it seems like the user should be automatically redirected to an error page, however nothing happens here. Also, my nuxt version is 2.15.8.

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue, so all I had to do, was add redirect to validate function, and redirect to the error page, like so:

```js
async validate({ params, redirect }) { //run-functions
  if (obj == undefined) {
    redirect('/not_found')
    return false
  } else {
    return true
  }
}
```